# BlackBerry Date Validator

Tags: validation, date, blackberry, blackberry-jde

Is there any easy way to validate input date in balckberry? I tried RegEx but couldn't success. Does any one have a validation method.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing date input over text? Why don't use DateField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you get date as a String in parts, use java.util.Calendar class to build a java.util.Date instance. In case of exception the entered date is not correct.

Intercept this exception in your validation method and return false.

Comment: And be careful with Timezones.